# Scanning QR Image With Zxing from Windows Phone Image Library

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, zxing, qr-code, scanning

We can scan images from camera with Zxing.Net but are there any solution to scanning existent images (like in library) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZXing can read existent images, its `Decode` method takes `WritableBitmap` as a parameter. So you can get the image from user library with PhotoChooserTask, get WritableBitmap and read it.

Using ZXing is demonstrated here: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Generating_and_scanning_barcodes_using_ZXing_on_Windows_Phone

```
_barcodeReader.Decode(_previewBuffer);
```

_previewBuffer in this case is WritableBitmap